# failed to publish release on play store: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

I've tried to resolve this problem for a few days but I can't understand what's the problem.
I've tried to publish my signed bundle on play store but I get this error:
"failed to run aapt dump badging: AndroidManifest.xml:49: error: ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value".

Then I've tried the command aapt dump badging on terminal and I get this error: "ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found".
This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/JUMP"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-7527687269802654~1998468299"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.GameOver"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@style/Theme.JUMP"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.StartGame"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="package.OtherActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.StartGameMixed"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="package.OtherActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.Pause"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="package.OtherActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.dipsapplus.JUMP.FirstGame"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JUMP.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="package.OtherActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've tried many things like flutter clean (which seems to do nothing) and other things found on internet. I really don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity GameOver has an attribute `android:label` which points to a style instead of a string, `@style/Theme.JUMP`.